# Firefox document.all issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8, document

I am trying to make my application compatible with all browsers and my code

```
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "theAction",
   "<script type='text/javascript'>
      function DoSave() {
        try {
          document.all('" + lbnSave.ClientID + "').click();
        } catch(e){}
      }
   </script>");
```

is working in IE8, Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox. I know that document.all is IE specific, but how do I rewrite this to work in Firefox too? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) which is cross-browser:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "theAction",
   "function DoSave() {
     try {
       document.getElementById('" + lbnSave.ClientID + "').click();
     } catch(e){}
   }", true);
```

Also, you can make your code cleaner. Fourth parameter set to `true` will add `<script>` tag automatically.